# ios fetching images for UIcollectionview controller

Tags: ios, networking, uicollectionview

I am fetching images from my server in collection view. But it takes long time to load the images from server. Is there any suitable solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you display image from server in Collection view then, you should download data in dispatchqueue.

But the best way to display image in collection view from server is caching of image.

There are many third party library available, here is the good one https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/README.md.

You can also download image and store it in local dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the IconDownloader class by Apple. Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/LazyTableImages_Classes_IconDownloader_m.html) .